# Run Elasticsearch docker container with FROM Busybox

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, busybox

I'm using a custom image from official elastic image:

[docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.4](https://docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.5)

I have a memory issue, so but in this image, I don't have Java tools to monitor memory.

Is it posible to use this image, but based on an "bigger" image with more tools to debug, like busybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to extend this image by creating a custom dockerfile and installing the tools that you need.

```
FROM elasticsearch:5.6.5
RUN <install tools you need>
```

The elastic search image is based on `openjdk:8-jre` which doesn't contain the development tools that come with the jdk.
If you compare the dockerfiles of [openjdk-jdk](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/a893fe3cd82757e7bccc0948c88bfee09bd916c3/8-jdk/Dockerfile) and [openjdk-jre](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/a893fe3cd82757e7bccc0948c88bfee09bd916c3/8-jre/Dockerfile) you can see that Java is installed under `/docker-java-home`

Thus you can use docker [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages) to copy over the jdk onto the elastic search image.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk as jdk

FROM elasticsearch:5.6.5
COPY --from=jdk /docker-java-home /docker-java-home
```

This will replace the jre installation inside `elasticsearch` image with the jdk version giving you the java developement tool. This is probably the most simple way.

Finally, you can do a "brute force" this where you rebuild the whole elastic search image by replacing the `FROM openjdk:8-jre` with `FROM openjdk:8-jdk` inside the [elasticsearch docker file](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/a893fe3cd82757e7bccc0948c88bfee09bd916c3/8-jdk/Dockerfile).